# Have a wheel listener exclusively consuming events

Tags: java, html

I have implemented a Java applet embedded in an html webpage. The applet implements a wheel listener in order to zoom in/out the displayed graphics. However, the browser is also interpreting the wheel movement and scrolling the page.
Is there a possibility to consume the wheel listener event exclusively by the Java applet, Whenever the mouse is over the applet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Events all implement a `consume` function which should do exactly what you want: [Docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/event/InputEvent.html#consume%28%29)

> consume
>
> public void consume()
>
> ```
> Consumes this event so that it will not be processed in the
> ```
>
> default manner by the source which originated it.

And yes MouseWheelEvent really implements (well inherits) this method ;)